# r random sampling keeping at least one level per column

Tags: r, sampling

hope someone can help me with this: im trying to figure out how to randomly sample a percentage of rows from a data.frame consisting of multiple (factor) columns asuring that in the resulting data.frame there is a least one level per column present.

here is some data:

```
    vs am gear carb
 1:  0  1  4  4
 2:  0  1  4  4
 3:  1  1  4  1
 4:  1  0  3  1
 5:  0  0  3  2
 6:  1  0  3  1
 7:  0  0  3  4
 8:  1  0  4  2
 9:  1  0  4  2
10:  1  0  4  4
11:  1  0  4  4
12:  0  0  3  3
13:  0  0  3  3
14:  0  0  3  3
15:  0  0  3  4
16:  0  0  3  4
17:  0  0  3  4
18:  1  1  4  1
19:  1  1  4  2
20:  1  1  4  1
21:  1  0  3  1
22:  0  0  3  2
23:  0  0  3  2
24:  0  0  3  4
25:  0  0  3  2
26:  1  1  4  1
27:  0  1  5  2
28:  1  1  5  2
29:  0  1  5  4
30:  0  1  5  6
31:  0  1  5  8
32:  1  1  4  2
```

randomly sampling 20% of the original data.frame resulting in something like this would be fine:

```
    vs am gear carb
 1:  0  1  4  4
 2:  1  1  2  1
 3:  0  0  3  2
 4:  0  0  4  3
 5:  0  1  5  6
 6:  0  1  5  8
```

here in each column each level of the factor is still present.

### my first attempt

function "stratified" from library "splitstackshape"/"fifer" (seems like the same function). also the suggested solution from the comments

```
DT <- as.data.table(mtcars)
DT <- DT[, lapply(.SD, as.factor), .SDcols = c("vs", "am", "gear", "carb")]

SFDT <-
  stratified(
    DT,
    c("vs", "am", "gear", "carb"),
    select = list(
      vs = levels(test$vs),
      am = levels(test$am),
      gear = levels(test$gear),
      carb = levels(test$carb)
    ),
    size = .5
  )
```

still does not return all the levels from the factor carb:

```
    vs am gear carb
 1:  1  0    3    1
 2:  1  0    3    1
 3:  1  1    4    1
 4:  1  1    4    1
 5:  0  0    3    2
 6:  0  0    3    2
 7:  1  0    4    2
 8:  1  1    4    2
 9:  0  0    3    3
10:  0  0    3    3
11:  0  0    3    4
12:  0  0    3    4
13:  1  0    4    4
14:  0  1    4    4
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice reproducible example using 'fifer::stratified' [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fifer/versions/1.0/topics/stratified).

Comment: thank you for your feedback! i edited my question, as your answer did not directly help me with solving my problem